# Php split and explode not working within production website

Tags: php

I have a split and explode function which I'm using on my website to show data but for some reason when I place the code into my production file and run it nothing comes up. The same code works perfect when I test it on a local server though...

```
<?php

          $page = file_get_contents("https://www.ato.gov.au/tax- 
professionals/prepare-and-lodge/due-dates/");

          $split = explode("</span><h1>", explode("</span></Div>", 
 $page)[0])[1];
          $split = str_replace("/tax-professionals/", 
 "https://www.ato.gov.au/tax-professionals/", $split);

          echo $split

        ?>
```

Comment: Start with `print_r($page)` in production to make sure the page is actually downloading and that it's not some sort of firewall issue. Then check your PHP version locally and the one on the server. Finally, try removing the `?>` from the end of the file... PHP has some annoying quirks with extra space after the `?>`, and it's often best to just remove it. Oh and make sure to put a `;` after `echo $split`.

Comment: You should look into DomDocument, or PHPQuery or something similar to parse the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your allow_url_fopen is on in your php.ini file on production server.

You can also check it via

echo phpinfo()

Comment: Could you please mention your operating system for your production? Or you can post your production website link in commnt.